# How to merge a heterogeneous array to a single document in MongoDb?

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb

The MongoDb of my website stores a single document for each user. Each user will answer a couple of questionnaire forms during his visit. The forms are stored in an array, but since the documents don't overlap, a flat, single document would suffice. For analysis, I wish to produce a flat table of all the answers over all the forms.

Consider the following data structure:

```
{
    "USER_SESSION_ID": 456,
    "forms": [
        {
            "age": 21,
            "gender": "m"
        },
        {
            "job": "Student",
            "years_on_job": "12"
        },
        {
            "Hobby": "Hiking",
            "Twitter": "@my_account"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "USER_SESSION_ID": 678,
    "forms": [
        {
            "age": 46,
            "gender": "f"
        },
        {
            "job": "Bodyguard",
            "years_on_job": "2"
        },
        {
            "Hobby": "Skiing",
            "Twitter": "@bodyguard"
        }
    ]
}
```

The form-documents all look different and have no conflicting fields, so I would like to merge them, yielding a tabular, flat structure like this:

```
{ 'USER_SESSION_ID': 456, 'age': 21, 'gender': 'm', 'job': 'Student', ... 'Twitter': '@my_account' }
{ 'USER_SESSION_ID': 678, 'age': 46, 'gender': 'f', 'job': 'Bodyguard',  ... 'Twitter': '@bodyguard' }
```

Using Python, this is a total no-brainer, looking like this:

```
for session in sessions:          # Iterate all docs
    for form in session['forms']: # Iterate all children
        session.update(form)      # Integrate to parent doc
    del session['forms']          # Remove nested child
```

In MongoDb I find this quite hard to achieve. I am trying to use the aggregate pipeline, which I imagine should be suitable for this.

So far I helped myself by unwinding my datastructure, like this:

```
db.sessions.aggregate(
    {
        '$unwind': '$forms'
    },
    { 
        '$project': {
            'USER_SESSION_ID': true,
            'forms': true
        }
    },
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$USER_SESSION_ID',
            'forms': <magic?!>
        }
    }
)
```

In the unwinding stage, I create a document with the parent's data for each child. This should be roughly equivalent to the double-for loop in my python code. However what I feel like I'm conceptually missing is the "Merge" accumulator upon grouping. In python, this is done with `dict.update()`, in underscore.js it would be `_.extend(destination, *sources)`.

How do I achieve this within MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with the aggregate pipeline for ages until I gave the mapReduce command a try. This is what I came up with:

```
db.sessions.mapReduce(
    function () {
        var merged = {};
        this.forms.forEach(function (form) {
            for(var key in form) {
                merged[key] = form[key];
            }
        });
        emit(this.USER_SESSION_ID, merged);
    },
    function () {},
    {
         "out": {"inline": true}
    }
)
```

The mapping step combines the elements, since there is no single $merging operator available as an aggregation pipeline step. The empty `reduce` function is required. The `out` either writes to a different collection or just returns the result (inline, what I'm doing here).

It looks a lot like the method that chridam showed in his answer, but actually uses a projection. His version is much closer to the way that my python code works, but for what I'm trying to do a projection is fine and doesn't change the original set. Note that the python code does that, but not chaning the input collection is quite useful!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which uses nested [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) method calls of the [**`find()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find) cursor to iterate over the cursor result and get the object keys for the elements within the `forms` array using [**`Object.keys()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
db.sessions.find().forEach(function (doc){
    doc.forms.forEach(function (e){ 
        var keys = Object.keys(e); 
        keys.forEach(function(key){ doc[key] = e[key] });
    });
    delete doc.forms;
    db.sessions.save(doc);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I managed to fix my problem using the mapReduce function, which allows for further processing! I love how close to my python code you got though, I didn't know this was possible! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @cessor No worries, glad you found the solution.